# Angular 2 or 4: How to add multiple instances of a child component

Tags: angular

Note: I have seen several questions like my title, but they don't solve my problem. Like:

- [Angular2 Parent Component with multiple instances of child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749885/angular2-parent-component-with-multiple-instances-of-child-component) (just code error)
- [Instance Angular 2 Component Two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818238/instance-angular-2-component-two-times/34818494) (this is about bootstrapping, not just components)

**Situation**
I have several template driven forms inside my angular application, with multiple date fields. I have made a special component (DatePickerComponent) that I insert as a child component in al these forms.

**Problem**
The variables inside the components are shared. Angular probably instantiates the same object, but I want different instances! I am note sure how to do this.

**What I think is the solution**
It probably has something to do with where you declare the DatepickerComponent. I declared it in the app.module.ts, but this creates one instance for the whole application. I don't know how to make sure that my parent component is forced to use two different child components.

**Reasoning**
I am doing this in a seperate component, because I don't have a date picker yet. Right now its a textbox with a pattern form validation. Later on I will make something better (a real date picker), and I don't want to copy paste code everywhere and make mistakes. With using 1 component, this is easily done.

**Concrete code**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from "@angular/core";
import {ControlContainer, NgForm} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datepicker-component',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  // Add viewProviders, so the input will be treated part of the form in the parent.
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class DatepickerComponent implements OnInit { // stuff }
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{ label }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="form-control" [ngModel]="date" (ngModelChange)="dateChange.emit($event)"
           #inputdate="ngModel" [required]="required" pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)02\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$"/>
    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="required && inputdate.invalid && inputdate.errors.required && (inputdate.dirty || inputdate.touched || triedSubmit)">Datum is verplicht.</span>
    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="inputdate.invalid && inputdate.errors.pattern && (inputdate.dirty || inputdate.touched || triedSubmit)" >Datum moet formaat dd-MM-yyyy hebben.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In some other page I use:

```
<form>
  <app-datepicker-component label="Actief vanaf" [(date)]="date1" [required]="true" [triedSubmit]="triedSubmit"></app-datepicker-component>

  <app-datepicker-component label="Actief tot" [(date)]="date2" [required]="false" [triedSubmit]="triedSubmit"></app-datepicker-component>
</form>
```

The AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // stuff
    DatepickerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // stuff
  ],
  providers: [
    // stuff],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Things that go wrong**
The date variable is shared because the same instance is used, which I don't want. Also if the validation triggers for one of the components, it will think the other components are invalid (which they aren't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it's not using the same instance. The problem is that they both belong to the same `form`, and are using the same value for `name`. This causes the underlying angular form object to treat them as the same.

Your options are to have them within separate forms, or use different `name` values, possibly by passing the name in as an input

Comment: If date1 is not null and date2 is null, and I add ngOnInit { console.log(this.date) }, I get two logs, date1 and then date2. However, both input textboxes are empty. When i fill date2 with a date, it fills both textboxes with date 2. How is changing the name going to solve that?

Comment: Because Angular stores the values within a map. It uses the name property as the key for that map. If the name values are the same, they will override each other. Here is a stackblitz showing that it works if you give different name properties https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mv8dkb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Magic! Thank you very much, the example was very helpful.